# How to print the value inside the another value?

Tags: python-3.x

i want to print the value of the 'phone' and email

```
contact = {
    'joe': {'phone': '123-4569', 'email': 'test@test.ph'},
    'gow': {'123-789466', 'test@gmail.com'}
}
print(list(contact.get('joe')))
```

My result is the only value of joe.

['phone', 'email']

Comment: why do you put it in a list before printing?

Comment: `contact['joe']['phone']` and `contact['joe']['email']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this,

```
dict.keys()
dict.values()


>>> contact = {
...     'joe': {'phone': '123-4569', 'email': 'test@test.ph'},
...     'gow': {'123-789466', 'test@gmail.com'}
... }
>>> print(contact['joe'].values())
>>> print(contact['joe'].keys())
dict_values(['test@test.ph', '123-4569'])
dict_keys(['email', 'phone'])

>>> print((contact['joe'].keys()))
['email', 'phone']
```

in `python3` if you want list you suppose to convert by using, `list()`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print a dictionary, it basically prints only the keys in the dictionary. And you are also converting the keys into a list using `list()` function.

To get the entire dictionary, you need to print the dictionary alone.

In this case, it is

```
print(contact.get('joe')))
```